# Multiple URL hash with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I have a search filter that  uses  **checkboxes** as an **input** to filter through different articles that have different or same categories ( seven to be exact) . I want the user to be able to filter the content and then share this generated link with someone else who would see the filtered results.
The problem that I am facing is that when a user checks more than one filter, beacuse URL has only the latest hash. Is it possible to append more than one hash in URL, or should I save all generated hashes in some sort of array and then just compare those values with my second code below?

**This is where I get hash for each clicked filter option:**

```
var elId = $(this).attr('id');
               

                if (elId != '') {
                    window.location.hash = elId ;
                }
```

**Code for clicking on each selected checkbox so that results are filtered when entering on page**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            var urlHash = window.location.hash; 
            console.log(urlHash);
            urlHash = urlHash.replace("#", "");
            urlHash = urlHash.replace(" ", "");
            urlHash = urlHash.replace("%20", "");
            urlHash = urlHash.toLowerCase();
          
            if (urlHash == 'infrastructure') {
                $('#Infrastructure').click();
            }
            else if (urlHash == 'development') {
                $('#Development').click();
            }
           
            else if (urlHash == 'sharepoint') {
                $('#SharePoint').click();
            }
            else if (urlHash == 'office') {
                $('#Office').click();
            }
            else if (urlHash == 'sql') {
                $('#SQL').click();
            }
            else if (urlHash == 'azure') {
                $('#Azure').click();
            }
            else if (urlHash == 'other') {
                $('#Other').click();
            }
           

        }
        catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Comment: Instead of using hashes, you could use query parameters. This allows you to define more than one variable in a URL. Documentation: https://branch.io/glossary/query-parameters/

Comment: Also, why are you checking urlHash on something to replace it with exactly the same? Just use elId right away?

Comment: The first code is inside the checkbox filter .click(function (){  });, so I can't access it outside. Plus with the second code being outside of click function I achieve that the code is executed immediately upon entering the page, so that the articles are filtered according to the given hash in the url. Hense the .click()

Comment: What @Wimanicesir means, is change your code to just `window.location.hash = elId`

Comment: Oh yea, I see it, updated.  Thank you. 
Still haven't figured out the part for appending values to url and then spliting it when page loads into X values based on checked filters

Comment: u can use use a seperator in hash for multiple values: `ww.xy.de/#foo=bar&test=213` you just need to split when parse

Comment: But I only get one hash at the time. It works with only one filter, but then the second overrides the one before. Should I dynamically check for checked boxes and then save the value of the checked ones and add that to url, and then split the URL and add click() function on those checkboxes?

Comment: So is your issue in *building* the hash or *reading* the hash?

Comment: `hash = $(".filter:checked").map((i,e) => e.id).toArray().join("&")`

Comment: Both acctually. I have to build the hash ( hashes) and then from that generated URL I have to read each added hash to filter through categories accordingly

Comment: With this code console.log() looks something like that:

hashAray: Development&SharePoint&Office  Can I append these values diectly to URL then ?

Comment: I've added this to URL now :

http://localhost:13658/Page/1#SharePoint&Office&SQL&Azure

Can I now split this somehow so that I only get values (SharePoint, Office, SQL etc..)

Comment: Found a solution for my case, thank you **freedomn-m** for your help. 

I first used map() function to get all checkboxes in an array: 

      var hashCheckBox = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map((k, e) => e.id).toArray().join("&")

And then added that value to my URL: `window.location.hash = hashCheckBox;`

I could then just check when the page has loaded if there is an exact word to output desired content among all. 


     if (urlHash.includes("azure")) {
                $('#Azure').click();
            }